# Multithreading/concurrent runing selenium Windows

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I'm currently working on a project with webparsing and using selenium together with `phantomJS`.

The project I wrote is working fine but the problem is that it is very slow, so I thought i might introduce multithreading in it.

I know that selenium is not multithread safe and each thread should have its own webdriver(just to be clear).

The point is:

I have an array with objects that are used in the url(only a part of it)
Currently I running for loop for the objects and navigate the driver to given xpath,  get data and initialize the object. To do it faster I want to create 4 threads where each thread should:

1. Initialize new web driver
2. Get the item from list that is not used yet.
3. Call different functions on this object

I'm not sure how I should start to create multiple drivers and put it all together. How I'm suppose to create the threads that are responsible for the work? I have read about the run override function and that st this place there should be the work that thread should do, but how it should know the next element from list to use?

So far I have following:

```
public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        private Objectx object
        private WebDriver driver;
        public MyThread(Objectx object){
            this.object = object;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            driver = driverSettings(driver);
            driver.navigate().to("website" + object.getNumber + ".html");
            function1(object);
            function2(object);
         }
    }
```

And in main method:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Now I have list of objects

```
    private static List<Objectx> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Objectx>();
```

Can I then use:

```
For (Objectx object : listOfObjects){
        Runnabble object.getNumber() = new MyThread(object).start()
}
```

Or how I'm supposed to add all the objects to create runnable list?

Comment: Explain what part you expect to be faster with two threads and why you think it will be faster.

Comment: @mentallurg , it will be faster since i can open multiple browser windows at once and use them in same time.

Comment: So every thread will have its own task. Then what exactly is the problem?

Comment: yea. the problem is what i'm supposed to use and how to exactly use it. How to create the given amount of threads and execute them on the given list of objects. I managed to make it run on thread ( if i have fx 4 objects it creates 4 threads but the problem is if i have 250 objects)

Comment: Are you trying to run you test scripts parallel mode to save time?

Comment: @YosuvaA no, I'm not using test scripts. This is to get data from many different websites with same pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the base steps.

1) Create a pool of threads. The number of threads does not depend on the size of objects to process. E.g. you can create a pool of 4 threads to process 250 objects.

2) When you create a thread, pass the list of objects to its constructor.

3) Each threads takes the the next object from the list and removes it from the list. You can use a queue instead of list.

4) Important: Access to the list (queue) should be synchronized, so that only one thread at a time can modify it. One of the easiest ways is to to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

5) Each thread in the run() retrieves the next task from the list (from the queue), processes it, retrieves the next task. If there are no more tasks, the thread exits its run() method.

**Update 1: (after the question updated)**

The name "MyThread" is misleading, because it is not a thread. I'd suggest you name it according to what it does, like "WebSiteParser". But for the functional result it doesn't matter :)

When you created your instances of runnable, you should submit them to the executor. It will execute them according to the number of threads in the pool.

**Update 2:**

Regarding reuse of Web Drivers: If you use ExecutorService, then I'd recommend you to create Web Drivers in advance, put them to a stack or a queue. When a thread starts its task, it should take a Web Driver from this stack or queue. When it completed its task, it should put its Web Driver back to the stack or queue. Again make sure the access to this stack or queue is thread safe.

Comment: I've edited the question, do you mind to take a look?

Comment: amazing! i managed to do it. but i have one problem more. Whenever i call run command i create new driver. is it possible to make a list of these and each thread is supposed to get the "free" driver? or each root keeps same driver for lifetime?